# nano not showing any text file content when I open a text file in terminal

Tags: nano

I'm trying to edit a text file in terminal using the nano command however when I do it and specify the correct location it shows nothing. If I go and open the actual text file then all the content is in there.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with an example of a specific command / file that you tried to open

Comment: You are perhaps getting the path to that file all wrong!

Comment: Most likely you've mistyped the filename. Using tab completion can help ensure the file you are trying to edit actually exists: https://www.howtogeek.com/195207/use-tab-completion-to-type-commands-faster-on-any-operating-system/

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that when you say it shows nothing, you mean `nano` doesn't open the said file. And that when you go and open the file to see its content, you're doing so through a GUI.

Nevertheless, with this assumption in mind, I'll suggest you do any of the following since I believe it should be an issue of user privilege(s):

1. Use `sudo` as a prefix to the command you're running on the terminal.

   ```
   $ sudo nano <file>
   ```

   Note that `<file>` includes both the `"file name"` and `"file extension"`. For example: `README.md`.
2. Edit the file as a user with high privileges such as `root`.

   ```
   $ sudo su
   ```

   Enter your password when prompted... then proceed as follows:

   ```
   # nano <file>
   ```

After any of the steps above, you should see your file content on your terminal (that's your file open). You can then proceed with any editing.

---

**NB:** Check the bottom of the terminal for any other available instructions once file editing has been enabled.